# timer_create(), expiry events during sleep

Tags: android, timer

I need some clarification in the usage of timer_create(). I understand how to use this function, set delay and assign the handler function etc.

I would like to know how to create timers using this fn which can generate expiry events even when the device (Android phone) is in low power state (sleep mode). I couldn't find this info from the man pages, perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction. My clock base is CLOCK_REALTIME and the required delay is in the order of msec. 
Timers based on CLOCK_REALTIME will be able to wake-up the processor even if it is in sleep state?

Answer (score 0):

try IOCTL RTC timer 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=414983&seqNum=4

with RTC_WKALM_SET